# Read Objects from JSON response and save in mutable array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

This is my JSON data:

```
let jsonArray = [
    "array": [12.34, 56.78],
    "users": [
        [
            "id": 987654,
            "info": [
                "name": "jack",
                "email": "jack@gmail.com"
            ],
            "feeds": [98, 23443, 213239, 23232]
        ],
        [
            "id": 654321,
            "info": [
                "name": "jeffgukang",
                "email": "jeffgukang@gmail.com"
            ],
            "feeds": [12345, 56789, 12423, 12412]
        ]
    ]
]
```

My code for to read "users" and "id"

```
let idArr = NSMutableArray()
let infoArr = NSMutableArray()
let usersArr = NSMutableArray()

for index in 0...1 { 
    infoArr.addObjects(from: (jsonArray["users"]![index] as! [String: Any])["info"] as! [Any]) 
} 
print("info arr : (infoArr)") 
for index in 0...1 { 
    idArr.addObjects(from: (jsonArray["users"]![index] as! [String: Any])["id"] as! [Any]) 
} 
print("id arr : (idArr)")
```

But I'm getting errors like:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSDictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>' (0x1079b8420) to 'NSArray' (0x106332008)
>
> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>' (0x1105ac550) to 'Swift.Array<Any>' (0x1105abf30).
>
> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Int' (0x11149f8c0) to 'Swift.Array<Any>' (0x1114c4f30).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var infoArr: [Any] = []
var idArr: [Any] = []

for i in 0..<(jsonArray["users"]!).count {
  infoArr.append((jsonArray["users"]![i] as! [String: Any])["info"])
  idArr.append((jsonArray["users"]![i] as! [String: Any])["id"])
}
```

Comment: Getting Error : Value of type '[Any]' has no member 'add'

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thank you very much and I will upvote

Comment: this leaves the content unknown

Comment: @Sh_Khan - But you can change the content at any time whenever you need it in another form.

Comment: @Sh_Khan - Also you can take the idArr as [Int] and infoArr as [Dictionary<String, Any>] if you need to be very specific about the content.

Comment: **STOP FORCE UNWRAPPING THINGS!**

Answer (score 0):

1- change this

```
["info"] as! [Any]
```

to

```
["info"] as! [String:Any]
```

2- and this

```
["id"] as! [Any]
```

to

```
["id"] as! NSNumber
```

//

```
var idArr = [NSNumber]()
var infoArr = [[String:Any]]()

for index in 0...1 { 
 infoArr.append((jsonArray["users"]![index] as! [String: Any])["info"] as! [String:Any]) 
} 
print("info arr : (infoArr)") 
for index in 0...1 { 
idArr.append((jsonArray["users"]![index] as! [String: Any])["id"] as! NSNumber) 
}
```

Comment: Getting this error Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[Any]'

Comment: Error :Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '[Any]'

Comment: change the array  ,,.

Comment: **STOP FORCE UNWRAPPING THINGS!**

Comment: @iOS i tried it myself and it works , only difference is let turned to var but json not edited

Answer (score 0):

```
**Check correct code**


  var idArr = [Int]()
    var infoArr = [[String:Any]]()
    let usersArr = [Any]()

    for index in 0...1 {
        infoArr.append((jsonArray["users"]![index] as! [String: Any])["info"] as! [String:Any])
    }
    print("info arr : \(infoArr)")
    for index in 0...1 {
        idArr.append((jsonArray["users"]![index] as! [String: Any])["id"] as! Int)
    }
    print("id arr : \(idArr)")
```